# Wire gauge to connect to chassis in van

Tags: batteries, inverter, wire, gauge, chassis

I'm building an AC electrical system for my van conversion and I'd like to know if there's a minimum wire gauge I should use to connect my negative bus bar to my van's chassis.

**Specs:**
I'm running a 2000W inverter that's connected to two 200AH batteries (12V) that are connected in parallel.
I'm using 2/0 "Heavy duty welding cable" to connect my batteries together as well as to connect my batteries to my inverter (which are connected through a 300A Class T fuse).

**Question:**
Given my setup, is it safe to use #4 "Heavy duty welding cable" (which is what I have lots of) to connect my negative bus bar to my chassis? (the bus bar is between the battery and inverter)

Comment: What rating is the fuse? The wire must be able to handle the worst case fault current. This depends on the fuse you have. Remember - the fuse is to protect the wire, not the load. There are ampacity tables on the ‘web that will tell you the rated current for your cable. That determines your fuse size.

Comment: The fuse between the batteries and the inverter is rated for 300A. I'll edit this in the question as well.

Comment: I think 300 Amps is too much for AWG 00 cable. I think you should use AWG 0000 or use a smaller 250 Amp fuse. I am not clear on what current will be passing through the number 4 cable. Are you using the chassis as a ground conductor between the inverter and battery? Or is this the chassis ground for the AC side of the inverter? You definitely cannot run 250 or 300 Amps through AWG 4 cable. If you are using the chassis for high current ground, you need to use the same cable to connect to the chassis as you are using for the positive leg. You also need excellent contact from cable to chassis.

Comment: Thanks for the info mkeith, sounds like I should give the company that sold me the inverter a call just to be safe. It the inverter came with the 2/0 cables and the fuse, so I'd be surprised if they aren't compatible. You increased my skepticism, so thank you!